# Save with the controls of the form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a windows application developed in c sharp with setup file generated. For that file I need to save the form with the controls and text with in controls. This application don't have any database. Can you suggest an extension method and also how to save the form?

Comment: What do you mean by "saving the controls"? Do you mean the value of them or something about the actual controls?

Comment: Suppose if we open ms word we can save,open,edit... and close it. In the same way my application also should be..i also want the extension for that to be saved

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to save controls. What you can do is create a serializable class to keep Form's data. You can serialize those settings and save. When you load the application next time you can deserialize and load those values to the form controls. This is one of the ways of doing it if you don't use a database to store data.

Comment: with what extension I need to save

Comment: You're going to need to write some code. Look into Serializing / Deserializing objects in c#. There's plenty out there.

Comment: @ swa : I think you are looking for a ready made way to do this which is not available unfortunately :-)